# What is a good ratio of Java threads to CPUs on Solaris?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Java application that has a fixed thread pool of fifteen, the machine, Solaris 10 SPARC, has sixteen CPUs. Adding the pool has greatly increased performance, but I'm wondering if I have too many threads in the pool. Would performance be better with less threads or does Solaris do a good job of thread scheduling.

Say the pool is heavily using fifteen CPUs, then other application threads demand CPU for various reason, concurrent garbage collection is a good example. Now, five CPUs are shared between the pool and other application threads. Then CPUs one through seven become free, will Solaris move the threads sharing time on the busy CPUs to the free CPUs?

If not, would it be better to keep the pool size smaller, so that there are always free CPUs for other application threads? Compounding the issue, CPU usage is very sporadic in the application.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Oh yeah, thanks for the edit, I was scratching my head to figure out what "Solaris 10 Spark" was...
@KaizenSoze: How many cores per CPU?
@SO community: Is threads to core count less relevant to performance analysis?

Comment: Thanks for the great comments. I should have added in the original question, there is no IO involved, it's very CPU intensive process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are doing only cpu intensive tasks (no IO) N+1 threads (where N is the number of cores) will give you the optimum processor utilization.
+1 because you can have a page fault, a therad can be paused to any reason or a small wait time during synchronization.

For Threads doing IO this is not really easy, you have to test the best size.
The book [Java concurrency in practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/) suggests this algorithm as starting point:

```
N = number of CPUs
U = target CPU utilization (0 <= U <= 1)
W/C = ration of wait time to cpu time (measured through profiling)

threads = N * U * (1 + W/C)
```

IBM uses the same algorithm in their article [Java theory and practice: Thread pools and work queues](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0730.html), with a fixed U=1.
The N+1 fact can be read too in the IBM article, to provide origins for both theses.

Answer (score 2):

It's generally fine to have a few more threads than CPUs, this can actually help overall throughput.

The reason for this is that several threads may be blocked on IO or sleeping at any given time. So having a few more threads ready to execute never hurts.

Comment: p.s. other point is that thread overhead is so small nowadays, there's very little real advantage to keeping thread count down, apart from a minor cache coherency effect.

Comment: The main cost in using threads is the complexity of the software, since suddenly you are forced to think about concurrency.

Comment: @samoz - true, but the "thought complexity" cost is broadly the same regardless of whether you're using 2, 16, or 1000 threads.  Almost all threadsafety issues are a simple binary thing that depends on there being *more than one* thread.  It's an unusual issue that would always work with 32 threads but would (potentially) break with 33 or more...

Answer (score -3):

Generally, if you can establish a 1 to 1 mapping between threads and CPUs, you will get optimal performance. That is assuming that user threads are mapped 1 to 1 with kernel threads. If I recall correctly, Solaris allows multiple kernel threads as well as user threads, so you should be ok in this respect. You will run into bottlenecks when more than one thread is using the same CPU.

As always, the best advice to your question about reducing thread pool size is: "Try and benchmark it." (but I suspect more will be better in this case.)

As for your question about other applications being run, Solaris will use a CPU to alternate between your thread pool and the other application. If a CPU becomes free though, Solaris will move some threads to the free CPU.

EDIT: [Here](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/threads/threads.html) is a link from Sun about how the Solaris and Java thread models interact.

Comment: -1: It's far more common to have applications that are sometimes doing blocking IO where having more than 1 thread per CPU improves performance, than to see actual performance bottlenecks due to too many threads.